# Phonegap+jQuery Mobile, overall sluggish controllers

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm using phonegap and jquerymobile to develop an Android app, I'm having a pretty hard time with overall sluggishness on stuff like buttons and select menus.

Sometimes they work fine, but most of the times it takes several taps to work, a lot of buttons get "stuck" on the hover state/pressed state, select menus are just pretty slow and my taps are registering different options from the ones I tapped.

One thing to note is that removing the `data-role="content"` from my pages seems to have a performance improvement (big case of wtf), I have also tried `$.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 0;`, this doesn't seem to have any effect.

My pages are extremely light so far (not rendering any content server side yet/all scripts are referenced locally/only 4 pages of pure html), I'm only using the slide effect (which works perfectly btw, no sluggishness on that department), it's the controllers that are killing me

I'm testing this on a 4.0 device, not sure if I am missing something, but if it's this clunky so soon into the project, I don't want think how it's going to look when we actually get started...

Answer (score 2):

jQuery Mobile on mid range and entry level phones sucks all time. Mark my word on it. If you run your app on a high end device like SIII or SIV or even on iPhone family then you will look that UI looks cool and less sluggishness.

Issue is simply because of the lack of processing power. When you release the product you have to inform your customers that on entry level phones, it’ll look ugly else, it’ll end up taking all memory and WebView or Browser will crash.

Comment: Is there another framework recommended for Phonegap? I see a lot of talk on the web and people seem to sit mostly with jQuery Mobile... I'd like to retain functionalities like transitions and ajax support.

Comment: jQuery Mobile enables you to use powerful UI controls that will take ages for single developer to develop. If you are ok with paid subscriptions check out [Kendo UI for mobile](http://www.kendoui.com/mobile.aspx). BTW did you check [Sencha UI](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch)? I hear Its much faster than JQM from my friends.

Comment: Try to dig on google on how to speed up JQM. There are several ways like disable user-scalable or disable shadowing (I don't remember the exact solution but it can give you some idea on what to search)